# some Figures are cut from right side in dvi but correct when using the tex file

Tags: floats, dvi

I am using winedt 6.0 and miktex 2.9

when i compile in winedt 6.0 using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> , the output pdf file is perfect.
but when creating the dvi file, some figures (eps files) are cut from the right side, i tried to make the figure smaller but still have the same problem.

Sample :

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
\usepackage{balance}
\usepackage[numbers,square, sort&compress]{natbib}

\usepackage{epstopdf}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

I am using winedt 6.0 , when i press Ctr+shift+p the pdf file is created without any    problems. But i need the (.dvi) file for the conference, when i create the dvi file some figures are cut from the right side and other are fine.

 I am converting matlab figures to eps (save as eps), then used the command epstool.exe --bbox --copy old.eps new.eps . I tried also changing the width at includegraphic but still have the same problem.
 \begin{figure}[t]
\centering
\includegraphics[keepaspectratio = false,width=0.95\linewidth, height =4.7cm]{fig2Resized2N.eps}
\caption{PCR versus the SNR for 3 available relay nodes case}
\label{PCR_vs_SNR}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The eps file in the linke beow:
http://www.mediafire.com/download/w055y467pcqmoko/fig2Resized2N.eps

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Now, i tested the minimal working example and it works fine but the complete file gives the same error. I am confused.

Comment: The problem happens when two figures are side by side at the top of the two columns or at the bottom.
When i forced new location of the figures, all figures appear perfect. How can i Solve this to allow the figures top be side by side.

Comment: Without a MWE that shows the problem it is hard to help. But FYI: the DVI format isn't for viewing. Convert it to ps or pdf to look at the output.

Comment: Thank you, I solved it.
I reduced the width of the ((two)) adjacent figures at the top of the page to width=0.95\linewidth.

Note: reducing only one of them will did not solve the problem.

Comment: If you solved your own question, then consider answering your own question by posting an MWE in the answer section so that it can be of use to future visitors on this site. Thanks!